# Manipulate Windows Process Input/Output Stream with Powershell?

Tags: powershell, process, io

Is there any builtin functionality with Powershell that allows you to examine system processes in great detail, and view/manipulate its I/O stream? Are there any community modules? Has anybody worked with process streams and know of any good references for such work?

Comment: What would a system process's I/O stream be? How would you want to manipulate it?

Answer (score 3):

The standard cmdlets provided by powershell allows you basic operations on processes. `Get-Process` cmdlet returns all running processes objects with detailed information about the process. You can also get the modules that the process loaded using the parameter `-Module`. You can use start/stop process cmdlets to manage the list of running processes.

However, the returned objects give you all information you may search for. `Get-Process` returns objects as [System.Diagnostics.Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx), while `Get-Process -Module` returns objects as [System.Diagnostics.ProcessModule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processmodule.aspx).

Comment: You may also be interested in getting processes as [Win32_Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394372%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) objects using the Get-WMIObject cmdlet.